# Change text encoding into Filelocator Pro?

Tags: encoding

I'm having problems viewing Cyrillic characters in FileLocator Pro.

There isn't a language menu option in the program's settings. Is there a solution?

[image]

Comment: What were you expecting to be shown? What format is the file in?

Answer (score 0):

You’re looking at an interpretation of binary data. From the context, it could be compressed data.